# Inserting values to database using JPA

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to read values of a column from a ms sql table via JPA hibernate and store them to another column of the same table after doing some manipulations on each value. The code below reads the column kNFormelZPS from table Kennzahl but then inserts a new record at the begging of the table with id 0, and writes the word new to that cell only! then it throws an exception saying the primary key can not be duplicated.I guess it tries to produces new records with Id 0.

```
public class ManageKennzahl {

private static EntityManagerFactory factory;
EntityManager em = null;
private static List<String> kNFormelZPs = new ArrayList<>();


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("migration");

    } catch (Throwable ex) {
        System.err.println("Failed to create sessionFactory object." + ex);
        throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
    }
    ManageKennzahl mk = new ManageKennzahl();

    mk.getKNFormelZPsFromKennzahl();
    mk.getKNFormelNPsFromKennzahl();
    mk.convert();
}

/**
 * 
 */
private List<String> getKNFormelZPsFromKennzahl() {
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    try {

        List<Kennzahl> kNFormelZPSs = em.createQuery("Select i From Kennzahl i ", Kennzahl.class).getResultList();
        for (Kennzahl kNFormelZPS : kNFormelZPSs) {
            String FormelZPs = kNFormelZPS.getFormelZPseudo();
            aquaQidbKNFormelZPs.add(FormelZPs);
        }

    } catch (HibernateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        em.close();
    }
    return kNFormelZPs;
}



private void convert() {
    Kennzahl kn = new Kennzahl();
    em = factory.createEntityManager();
    for (String fomelZPs : kNFormelZPs) {
        em.getTransaction().begin();    
        kn.setFormelZGL1(fomelZPs + "new");
        em.persist(kn);
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: why would a JPA application be playing with "HibernateException" ?! How can anyone comment on that without the Entity? Why not debug it by looking at the LOG?

Comment: You seem to always persist the same `Kennzahl` instance.

Answer (score 0):

the main problem was not using merge in order to avoid creating new entities.

```
private void convert() {
Kennzahl kn = new Kennzahl();
em = factory.createEntityManager();
for (Kennzahl qidbKennzahl : aqidbKennzahlen) {
  qidbKennzahl.setFormelZGL1(qidbKennzahl .getFormelZPseudo() + " test");
  em.merge(aquaQidbKennzahl);
  }
em.getTransaction().commit();
}
```